# Images do not appear in applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, paint, keylistener

I am working on a game.I want to add images to the applet but they do not appear there until I resize or minimize the applet.I do not know whether my image observer is wrong or not.
The images are in right path.Their in build and class folder with correct spelling. What is wrong with my code?
any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class game extends JApplet implements KeyListener, Runnable {

ScreenDir sd;
Image ball;
Image flower;

public void init() {

    sd = new ScreenDir(this);
    ball = getImage(getCodeBase(), "ball.jpg");
    ballb = new Ball(50, 50, 30, 40, Color.red, ball, sd);
    sd.add(ball);
    flower = getImage(getCodeBase(), "flower.gif");
     //class Flower is just defined like class Ball
    flowerf = new Flower(60, 100, 30, 30, Color.green, flower, sd);
    sd.add(flower);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    sd.draw(g);

}

//These are for moving the ball

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}}}



  public class ScreenDir {

ArrayList<Object> olist;
JApplet parent;

public ScreenDir(JApplet parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    olist = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void add(Object o) {
    olist.add(o);
}

Image Img;
Graphics oG;

Img  = parent.createImage(parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight());
oG  = offImg.getGraphics();

for(int i = 0;i<olist.size ();i++){
         olist.get(i).draw(offG);
}

g.drawImage (Img,0, 0, parent);
 }


    public class Ball extends Object {

ScreenDir sd;

public ball(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c, Image pi, ScreenDir sd) {
    {
        this.sd = sd;
    }
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(pi, x, y, w, h, null);
}


public abstract class Object {

    int x, y, w, h;
    Color c;
    Image pi;

    public Object(int x, int y, int w, int h, Color c, Image pi) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.c = c;
        this.pi = pi;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g) {
    }
```

Comment: Provide an ImageObserver to the draw method, this way, you can pass it to drawImage (ps JApplet is an ImageObserver)

Comment: you mean in Ball class in method draw I change "null" to "this". But it makes error.says cast to image observer and doesn't work right.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: No, I said pass it ImageObserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets load images asynchronously, so it is likely the images are not fully loaded before the applet goes to paint.  But every Java component worth mentioning implements an `ImageObserver` that means it will get updates on image loading.  So to fix the problem, change this:

```
g.drawImage(pi, x, y, w, h, null);
```

To **this:**

```
g.drawImage(pi, x, y, w, h, this);
```

### Update

I mistakenly thought the `drawImage` method was part of the `JApplet` (which is an `ImageObserver`).  You might simply change the method declaration & painting line to:

```
public void draw(Graphics g, ImageObserver io) {
    g.drawImage(pi, x, y, w, h, io);
}
```

Then to call it, change:

```
sd.draw(g);
```

To:

```
sd.draw(g, this);
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: game.Ball cannot be cast to java.awt.image.ImageObserver

Comment: because when i change "null" to "this" it cast to image observer and change like this:g.drawImage(pi,x,y,w,h,(Image Observer ) this);

Comment: You really need to learn what these messages mean, as well as what things like implementing an interface achieves.  Having said that, I changed my answer to address this new (different) problem.